# Aura Trample removed by High Priest of Penance

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I've been searching high and low for this: say a [High Priest of Penance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=High%20Priest%20of%20Penance) (with an indestructible aura) blocks a creature with [Rancor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rancor), i.e. trample. Can I stop the trample effect by destroying either the creature or the enchantment, before trample happens? Since it **first** assigns damage to the priest who then can destroy a permanent...?

> 702.19b The controller of an attacking creature with trample **first** assigns damage to the creature(s) blocking it.

Answer (score 7):

You can't stop your opponent from trampling over your High Priest this way. Although you are correct that trample damage is not *assigned* simultaneously between creatures and players, it is *dealt* simultaneously.

> 510.2 Second, all combat damage that's been assigned is dealt simultaneously.

So both you and your High Priest are dealt damage at the same time. At that point, you may use your Priest's ability, but destroying the attacking creature or aura will have no effect on what already happened.